# Need help in understanding a SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a following query. It uses only one table (Customers) from `Northwind` database.
I completely have no idea how does it work, and what its intention is. I hope there is a lot of DBAs here so I ask for explanation. particularly don't know what the `OVER` and `PARTITION` does here.

```
WITH NumberedWomen AS
(
    SELECT CustomerId ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (
                PARTITION BY c.Country 
                ORDER BY LEN(c.CompanyName) ASC
            ) 
                women 
                FROM Customers c
)

SELECT * FROM NumberedWomen WHERE women > 3
```

If you needed the db schema, it is [here](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v722/barkah/northwind-data-model-diagram.png)

Comment: What does the length of a company name have to do with women? And who would number them?

Comment: @sjngm Don't know, not my code. The developer must have been bored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.Country ORDER BY LEN(c.CompanyName) ASC)
```

assigns continuous row numbers to records within each `country`, ordering the records by `LEN(companyName)`.

If you have these data:

```
country   companyName
US        Apple
US        Google
UK        BAT
UK        BP
US        GM
```

, then the query will assign numbers from `1` and `3` to the `US` companies and `1` to `2` to `UK` companies, ordering them by the name length:

```
country   companyName   ROW_NUMBER()
US        GM            1
US        Apple         2
US        Google        3
UK        BP            1
UK        BAT           2
```

Answer (score 2):

`ROW_NUMBER()` is a ranking function.

`OVER` tells it how to create rank numbers.

`PARTITION BY` *[expression]* tells the `ROW_NUMBER` function to restart ranking whenever *[expression]* contains a new value

In your case, for every country, a series of numbers starting with 1 is created. Within a country, the Companies are ordered by the length of their name (shorter name = lower rank).

The final query:

> SELECT * FROM NumberedWomen WHERE women > 3

selects all customers except if the company-country combination is part of one of the companies with the 3 shortest names in the same country.